# Error System.Int32[] C#

Tags: c#

soy principiante en esto de la programacion y tengo un error que me sale al querer hacer un procedimiento que genere numeros aleatorios dentro de un array

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           
            int[] array1 = new int[10];

            Array(array1);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void Array(int[] array1)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
               
                array1[i] = random.Next(1, 11);
               
            }
            Console.WriteLine(array1);

        }
```

ese es el codigo en cuestion y el error que me tira al compilar es System.Int32[]

Calculo que hay algun error con el tipo de dato pero no puedo solucionarlo, vi algunos topics donde algunas personas tenian este mismo error pero no puedo saber bien que es

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? `System.Int32[]` no nos da mucha información. Si dijeras `NullPointerException` si nos daríamos cuenta porque es el nombre del error y es muy frecuente.

Comment: Tu código no tiene ningún error. Si lo que quieres es imprimir el array, usa algo cómo `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", array1));`.  La línea `Console.WriteLine(array1);` no funciona como esperas.

Comment: Gracias a ambos!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

No es un error, sino que estas imprimiendo por consola un objeto array1, y se llama al [metodo ToString](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-6.0#comentarios) de dicho objeto que por default, imprime en cadena de texto el nombre de la tipo de objeto o clase que es en este caso es un array de enteros, por eso imprime "System.Int32[]".
De la ayuda puedes leer [metodo ToString](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-6.0#comentarios)

> Las implementaciones predeterminadas del Object.ToString método devuelven el nombre completo del tipo del objeto.

O sea, en tu ejemplo

```
//Definicion de 
int[] array1 = new int[10];

//..y cuando ejecutas esta linea imprime en consola System.Int32[]
Console.WriteLine(array1);
```

Segui tu ejemplo para poder imprimir en consola un array

- Puedes ver tu ejemplo de codigo aquí (y ejecutarlo online) https://dotnetfiddle.net/8CemIq

Que para imprimir en pantalla los valores puedes utilizar

```
Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", array1));
```

Enlaces que te puden ayudar

- [Object.ToString Método](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-6.0)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía